# How to generate struct definition in the JNI header file with the javac or javah commands?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javac, javah

Given a class such as:

```
class Position {
   float   x;
   float   y;

   public static native long instance();
   public static native float getX(long ptr);
   public static native float getY(long ptr);
   public static native long delete(long ptr);
}
```

when generating the native header file, I would like the struct definition corresponding to the fields of the class to be included in the headers. Something like:

```
struct Position {
   float x;
   float y;
}
```

Running the command

```
javac -classpath bin -d . -h jni src/Position.java
```

with Java 11 or the command

```
javah src/Position
```

with Java 8 doesn't generate the struct.

I found the desired behaviour described in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javah.html) for javah (not sure how valid they are currently) stating `The .h file contains a struct definition whose layout parallels the layout of the corresponding class.`

I would like to know if it's possible to achieve what I described above with `javac -h`. If not was it ever possible and if so, what were the reasons for the change? Moreover what alternatives do I have?

Comment: I think it's a legacy from the NMI (The JNI of JDK 1.0.2) or LLNI (Something similar). The code for generating the LLNI headers is [this]  (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/tools/javah/LLNI.java.html) and shows, that a structure is created

Comment: Look here, https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_langtools/blob/06b2a96e80a08ba77dacf797596f0679bbd7bafd/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javah/JavahTask.java#L223 Try running with `-Xllni`. It *should* generate a header with a structure.

Comment: What are you actually planning to do with it, though? You cannot (directly) use these generated structs to access fields Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

#### Question

What steps can be used to generate a JNI header file for the Java class below?

```
public class Position {
    float x;
    float y;
    public static native long instance();
    public static native float getX(long ptr);
    public static native float getY(long ptr);
    public static native long delete(long ptr);
}
```

#### Steps to follow

1. Verify using JDK 11 – you mentioned trying versions 8 and 11, so I'm showing 11

   ```
   % javac -version
   javac 11.0.14
   ```
2. Run [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9) using `-h` option and "." to write generated files to current directory

   ```
   % javac -h . Position.java
   ```
3. Verify contents of generated header file

   ```
   % cat Position.h
   /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
   #include <jni.h>
   /* Header for class Position */

   #ifndef _Included_Position
   #define _Included_Position
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
   #endif
   /*
    * Class:     Position
    * Method:    instance
    * Signature: ()J
    */
   JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_Position_instance
     (JNIEnv *, jclass);

   /*
    * Class:     Position
    * Method:    getX
    * Signature: (J)F
    */
   JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL Java_Position_getX
     (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

   /*
    * Class:     Position
    * Method:    getY
    * Signature: (J)F
    */
   JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL Java_Position_getY
     (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

   /*
    * Class:     Position
    * Method:    delete
    * Signature: (J)J
    */
   JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_Position_delete
     (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

   #ifdef __cplusplus
   }
   #endif
   #endif
   ```